# ProgrammingError - relation "blog_app_post" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_app_post"

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I have a problem with my database every time I deploy it to heroku.
The code works okay on localhost but shows ProgrammingError when deployed.

When ever I remove the category from the codes, it seems to work but still having another issue with the auth dashboard.

Here is the *view.py* code

```
class BlogView(ListView): 
    model = Post 
    template_name = 'blog.html' 
    ordering = ['-post_date'] 
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        genres_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(BlogView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        
    
        context["genres_menu"] = genres_menu
        print(context)
        return context
```

Here is the *model.py* code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

    
    class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('blog')

class Post(models.Model): 
title = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="thumb_images/blog_post") 
snippet = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='This is a default snippet') 
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')



def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

def \__str_\_(self):
    return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog')
```

Here is the *url.py* code

from .views import BlogView

```
urlpatterns = \[
path('blog/', BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),
\]
```

Here is the template code

```
{% if genres_menu %} 
    <div class="widget-area">
    
    <div class="widget-collapse-btn">                    
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                            <h4 class="widget-collapse-title">Categories</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <div class="card card-body none-box">
                            <ul class="category-collapse">
                                {% for item in genres_menu %}
                                <li class="category-collapse-list">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a>
                                </li>
    
                                {% endfor %}
    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
    {% endif %}
```

I tried clearing the database with - python manage.py flush, makemigration and then migrate once again, but it remained the same.

Comment: Are you using SQLite for your database?

Comment: Yes, it is SQLite.

Comment: In particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38136409/354577

Comment: How can I backup my database locally when live on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of issue even flushing the migrations won't work you just have to drop that table blog_app_post. After you run `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` after the migration run `python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001_initial` this will generate all the schema of that particular app then look for the table blog_app_post schema and copy it then create that table manually if your DB is postgres you just connect to DB and paste that schema.
NB: This solution is actually good in development mode or local server

Comment: Throwing up your hands and dropping a table isn't generally a good solution. What if it contains data?

Comment: How do I drop the table?