# Why Django migration on second system does not work

Tags: python, django

I developed my application on my Laptop and wanna run them on a Raspberry Pi.

On my laptop it works very well, but on my RPi it does not work. 
I receive that the Database and the tables are not exist. I receive the same error when i run `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py makemigration`

All the migration files are also in the repository. 
How can I create the DB and the columns by a django manage.py command?

**ERROR MESSAGE**

`raise original_exception
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'motorcontrollsystem.motorControll_motormapping' doesn't exist")`

After the Server has started, a process start with --> `apps.py --> ready(self):{ ... }` could this bea problem? if yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the error that you receive ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535983/migration-clashes-with-forms-py)