# Relation does not exist when execute makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm using Postgres and Django.
I changed my server on localhost to Amazon EC2.

However, when I went to do 'python manage.py makemigrations' or 'python manage.py makemigrations myapp' appeared to me the following error:
Relation [table_name] does not exist.

Relationships / tables are not created in the Database.

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'myapp',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
]
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'freguesia',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

The error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
> >         return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
> >     psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_servico" does not exist
> >     LINE 1: ..."myapp_servico"."id", "myapp_servico"."nome" FROM "myapp_ser...
> >                                                                  ^

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/PortalJunta/PortalJunta/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from myapp import views
  File "/home/ubuntu/PortalJunta/myapp/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from myapp.forms import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/PortalJunta/myapp/forms.py", line 145, in <module>
    class RequerimentoForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/ubuntu/PortalJunta/myapp/forms.py", line 157, in RequerimentoForm
    servico = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=opcoes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 779, in __init__
    self.choices = choices
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 796, in _set_choices
    value = list(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1103, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 828, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myapp_servico" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."myapp_servico"."id", "myapp_servico"."nome" FROM "myapp_ser...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Run your existing migrations first

Comment: @Brobin i do not have any previous migrations :(
my database is empty, because makemigrations doesn't work

Comment: You didn't makemigrations on localhost? You only have to make them once.

Comment: A) What version of Django are you using
B) What happens when you run manage.py migrate
C) Are you sure you have myapp in your list of apps in settings.py

Comment: Include the full traceback in your question. It will show you where your code is trying to access the database before the migration has been created.

Comment: @Foon.. when i run manage.py migrate is same error. Django 1.11.1.

Comment: @Alasdair see my settings.py

Comment: @Brobin I  did migrations on localhost. If I did on localhost, the app run normally

Comment: Put your app after all the contrib ones in settings. Does your app relate to the user model or something?

Comment: Brobin, App after all contrib settings does not work. Relate to the user model? I use models.py

Comment: I asked to see the full traceback, not the settings.

Comment: Alasdair i put traceback

Comment: The traceback is showing you that the problem is in your `RequerimentoForm`. It is trying to fetch choices from the database before the table has been created.

Comment: [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726396/upgrading-from-django-1-6-to-1-9-python-manage-py-migrate-failure/37747009#37747009).

Comment: But I can not create the database tables, because this error :(

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. It's work!!!